# Facebook C# SDK - Api.Get("me/events") not returning events

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've tried to return the user events but with no success.

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
dynamic eventos = app.Api("me/events");
```

In this example, am i doing something wrong? The user is already authenticated (i can get his information, posts of wall, etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ask for the "user_events" extended permission. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/